# IMCE module button not showing for Editor role?

Tags: 6, users, files

I have given the Editor role literally every single permission, yet the button still only shows for admins. Am I missing a setting somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was indeed missing a setting somewhere. You have to assign a user profile to the role before they see the button in site configuration -> IMCE.